# Help reducing 3-SAT to 3-COLORING

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, np

I am working on showing that 3-colorability is NP-complete. I read a few articles and walkthroughs on this but none are really clicking. I get to this part

> "Then for every variable xi that appears in the instance of Satisfiability, we connect a
>        vertex xi to a vertex xi, and we connect both xi and xi to red. This is illustrated
>        below for a case where there are (only) 3 variables."

I think what they mean is something like this:

```
x1----x1*     x2----x2*      x3----x3*
 \   /         \   /          \   /
  \ /           \ /            \ /
   R             R              R
```

But my question is, what exactly is this step doing?

With a little bit more thought, is this step just showing that given xi to be one color, then xi* has to be another, but also cannot be R, as they are both connected to it?

Comment: Let green = true, and blue = false.  Your construction then uses a 3-colorability constraint (each pair xi,xi* must have one green and one blue, since the other node is always red) to express a 3-SAT constraint (each pair xi, xi* must have one true and one false).

Comment: For the future, this sort of question would be easier to answer if you told us all of the relevant context (e.g., the rest of the reduction, or a link to a description of this reduction, or something).  In this case it is possible to guess at what the rest looks like, but it would be better not to make people work harder than necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the goal of this construction is to try to assign true or false to each variable. The color assigned to x will determine whether it's true or false, and there's an edge from x to ¬x to ensure that each variable and its negation get different values. The edge from each variable to R ensures that there are only two possible colors that can be assigned to x, one of which means true and one of which meand false.

Hope this helps!